# How to reference an initialized embedded RavenDB instance in a Class Library?

Tags: asp.net-membership, ravendb, class-library, multiple-databases

My scenario is this:

I have a custom [RavenDB membership provider](https://github.com/wilby/RavenDBMembership) that is implemented in a class library (DLL). This provider needs to access a database to store and retrieve User and Role information. I'd like to use the same app database to store membership information to avoid having one more database.

I don't know how to get a reference to the already initialized database (app database) inside the class library code. I think I'm going the wrong way here... :)

Some code:

```
bool embeddedStore = Convert.ToBoolean(config["enableEmbeddableDocumentStore"]);

if (embeddedStore)
{
    _documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore()
    {
        // Here I'm using the same connection string used by the app.
        // This gives me an error when I try to open a session in the DocumentStore.
        ConnectionStringName =
            config["connectionStringName"]
    };
}
else
{
    _documentStore = new DocumentStore()
    {
        ConnectionStringName =
            config["connectionStringName"]
    };
}
```

This is the connection string present in Web.config:

```
<add name="RavenDB" connectionString="DataDir = ~\App_Data\Database" />
```

How can I reuse the same database within the custom membership provider? Any ideas?

I thought about moving the class library code files to the Web project. This way I could get a reference to the `DocumentStore` easily, but the code wouldn't be as organized as I'd like.

I also tried to use 2 RavenDB databases: 1 for the app and 1 for the membership provider, but as I'm running RavenDB in its embeddable fashion I couldn't get it working.

These are the errors I got during my attempts so far:

```
RavenDB Could not open transactional storage.

Temp path already used by another database instance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the instance of the opened document store to your dll. 
You can do that using a container or by providing an API call to do that.
You can't have two instance using the same db.

Comment: Holy Jesus... I didn't want to go the container way since it would be too much for what I need. After your answer a light was turned on and I went the API call way. I did what is described here: https://github.com/csainty/Glimpse.RavenDb/wiki/How-to-use Now I'm using this after initializing RavenDB app instance: `RavenDBMembership.Provider.RavenDBMembershipProvider.AttachTo(_documentStore);`